# http: ContentLength=99 with Body length 0

Tags: http, go

I have this function to execute http request

```
func do(r *http.Request) (response *http.Response, e error) {
    r.Header.Set(SessionHeader, client.SessionId)
    response, e = client.Do(r)
    if e != nil {
        return nil, e
    }
    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusConflict {
        client.SessionId = response.Header.Get(SessionHeader)
        r.Header.Set(SessionHeader, client.SessionId)
        response, e = client.Do(r)
        if e != nil {
            return nil, e
        }
        return
    } else if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, errors.New("status Not OK")
    }
    return
}
```

So I make a request, than if my session id is not valid, I set header from response and try again. The issue is that the Body got flushed when I do this and this error pops up:

```
Post http://localhost/api: http: ContentLength=99 with Body length 0
```

How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: Never re-use a `http.Request` for multiple requests.

Comment: You're also not consuming or closing the response body.

Comment: @Adrian out of curiosity, why shouldn't one reuse http requests?

Comment: @Adrian So, how can I achieve my goal not reusing http.Request? I need to get session id from header and than resend request with same body

Comment: @MadWombat: you can reuse requests, but you must ensure that there are no outstanding calls with the same request: `Callers should not mutate or reuse the request until the Response's Body has been closed`.

Comment: @MadWombat it requires some care to do without causing yourself difficult-to-troubleshoot issues, and the cost of creating a new `Request` is relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

Create a request and use it.

```
func do(r *http.Request) (response *http.Response, err error) {
    r.Header.Set(SessionHeader, client.SessionId)
    response, err = client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusConflict {
        // Get SessionId
        client.SessionId = response.Header.Get(SessionHeader)

        // Create Request
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com", nil)   
        req.Header.Set("SessionHeader", client.SessionId)

        response, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return
    } else if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, errors.New("status Not OK")
    }
    return
}
```